# Simple bash function to check if a ssh session succeeded or not

Tags: bash, ssh

When I'm at home, I want to connect to my server using my local network because it's faster than connecting to it's external IP address. But I want a function that connects automatically to my internal IP's SSH session, with capability for parameters, and if it fails try the external IP (and, again use the parameters).

So far what I have is this, and it seems like it should work, and I'm having a heck of a time debugging it.

```
ssh_home() { if ssh user@192.168.2.2 "$@" then echo; else echo "WARNING: NOT on home connection!"; ssh user@host.me -p 10000 "$@"; fi; }
```

The error message I'm currently getting is:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `else'
```

But I've looked up if else statements, and I'm pretty sure I'm doing it right.. Maybe my eyes are completely missing something though.

Comment: `echo "";` will prevent the error. You just need to tell it to `echo` something. The *empty-string* will do. By the way, an `if ping -c1 192.168.2.2; then connect home; else connect external; fi` may be a better approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot a semicolon in front of the `then`:

```
ssh_home() { if ssh user@192.168.2.2 "$@"; then echo; else echo "WARNING: NOT on home connection!"; ssh user@host.me -p 10000 "$@"; fi; }
```

In any case, why echo there nothing? why not reverse the condition:

```
ssh_home() { if ! ssh user@192.168.2.2 "$@"; then echo "WARNING: NOT on home connection!"; ssh user@host.me -p 10000 "$@"; fi; }
```

And why not write the function on multiple lines so it's easier to read:

```
ssh_home() {
    if ! ssh user@192.168.2.2 "$@"; then
        echo "WARNING: NOT on home connection!"
        ssh user@host.me -p 10000 "$@"
    fi
}
```

Comment: Live saver, thank you so much! And, I actually have no reason to be doing it all inline. I'm so used to doing everything in one line I completely forgot about breaking it down haha. Thanks!